# Make Linux Mint taskbar drag-n-drop work smooth like in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, linux-mint

I'm specifically asking how to change task bar in Linux Mint Cinnamon. That's how it currently works:

[image: Mint drag-n-drop]

As you can see, you drag an icon and replace another icon. In Windows it's a little bit more flexible and rearranges the icons as you drag one icon. I want it to look like this:

[image: Windows drag-n-drop]

It seems like taskbar is referred to as "panel" on Linux Mint. How can I change this mechanism? I've not found a related setting.

Comment: Mint is based on Ubuntu and Debian. I have Ubuntu here and the panel is not drag and drop. I confirmed this when trying to re-arrange my panel.

Comment: @John Are you sure you used Cinnamon? In Cinnamon drag-n-drop works, like I've shown.

Comment: I use Ubuntu and there is no way to drag and drop in the Panel. These distributions are all based on the same basic Linux.